# How to automatically load subviews for testing?

Tags: ios, testing, automation

I'm writing an iOS app that has a problem on a view that's about 4 taps deep into the `UINavigation` stack. It's becoming a pain to have to repeatedly tap tap tap through the simulator to drill down to the `UIViewController` I need every time I want to run the thing.

Is there a way to automate this?

I tried just instantly calling `[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectIndex...` manually, however that blows up because data hasn't been loaded into the table yet...

I'd prefer something fast w/o a lot of overhead to it - otherwise it'll take more time to implement the solution than I'd save by not tapping the screen 4 times...

Thanks for any insight you guys can provide.

Comment: Investigate UIAutomation.  There are various posts on StackOverflow about using this.  It's been available since iOS 4.

Comment: I briefly looked into UIAutomation, but this didn't pass the "takes more time than just tapping the button 4 time" test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this all the time - in the appDelegate, I just add some code wrapped in a #ifdef that just makes the subview the initial view of the navigation controller. Once you get the subview working you can turn the ifdef off. Using the technique will save you lots of time - in fact I'm using it right now to add functionality to my app in the store.

Comment: This is a great idea. I ended up just pushing my desired view onto the nav stack from the appdelegate and it's all perfect. Thanks!